# Word for all discovered knowledge

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

Is there a word that describes a person who has complete knowledge of everything humanity has ever discovered or produced, not being omniscient?

Comment: Is there such a person? If not, why would there be a specific word to describe them?

Comment: The Mind of God. Reference: My Town, the play

Comment: @Lambie, God is believed to be omniscient, while the OP is looking for a word for a being that is not omniscient.

Comment: The use of phrases like "the sum of human knowledge" suggests there's no one word.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, that's my point. There is not such thing.

Answer (score 1):

I sincerely doubt that such a person exists, so having a word to describe him would seem rather superfluous. I suppose we have words for ideals that no one has ever perfectly attained, but we generally use the same words for partial attainment. Like if I say someone is "humble", I don't necessarily mean that he practices perfect humility, just that he does better at this than most people.

There are the words "renaissance man" and "polymath" to describe someone with a broad range of knowledge. Either term can be used to refer to someone who knows about history, science, math, etc.